# What gui internet speed testing applications are available?

Tags: software-recommendation, internet

I want a GUI internet speed testing application (a webapp will suffice if it is **not flash**) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long time ago I used [TPTest](http://www.datanom.net/tptest-gui/index.html) for the job.

Comment: Perfect for the job!

Answer (score -1):

I've used this [web app](http://speakeasy.net/speedtest/) often (they have a nice Android app too)